# Triggering redirect from from React NavMenu removes the menu

Tags: reactjs, .net-core

I'm working with a .NET Core Web Application using the React template. I added a logout button to the NavMenu and when you press it, it triggers handleLogout which logs the user out, sets the logoutCallSuccess state to true, and then triggers a redirect back to the login page on the next render cycle.

When this happens, it returns to the login page but the NavMenu has been removed. This isn't intended (currently) and when the user logs back in the user has no NavBar to navigate with.

```
render() {
    if (this.state.logoutCallSuccess) {
        console.log("NavMenu: Redirecting to Login page.");
        return < Redirect to="/user/login" />;
    }
    console.log("derp.");
    return (
        <header>
            <Navbar className="navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm ng-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3" light>
                <Container>
                    <NavbarBrand tag={Link} to="/">Tcabs.Presentation</NavbarBrand>
                    <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleNavbar} className="mr-2" />
                    <Collapse className="d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse" isOpen={!this.state.collapsed} navbar>
                        <ul className="navbar-nav flex-grow">
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" to="/counter">Counter</NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" to="/fetch-data">Fetch data</NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem>
                                <button onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</button>
                            </NavItem>
                        </ul>
                    </Collapse>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
        </header>
    );
}
```

Is there some other way I should be triggering the redirect other than return < Redirect to="/user/login" />; ?

I would have thought it'd have the same effect as the to="" attribute used on the NavLink but I guess not.